# Declare a variable in a URL and assign it a value in Javascript when navigating to a page

Tags: javascript, html, query-string, location-href

I'm relatively new to HTML (and programming in general), and I'm trying to declare a variable and assign it a value when I navigate to a page. What I have is a line of code like this:

```
function() navigate {window.location = "myPage.html?myVar=1";}
```

When I run the function, the new page will load, but whenever I try to access the variable, I get an error saying the variable is undefined. However, if I define the variable in the new page, for example `<script>var myVar;</script>`, the value is set to null rather than the value that I try to set it to in the navigate function I used earlier.

I can't think of any solution to this, and my error probably stems from my misconceptions about how the `?` at the end of the url works, but I can't find a good explanation of how it works anywhere.

Comment: The query parameters in the URL have nothing to do with JavaScript. They are mainly intended to be processed by the server. You can access them with JavaScript though, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter. URLs, HTML and JavaScript are three independent technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string variables are intended for passing data to the server when we request a page, however you could still access them using javascript, checkout this Stackoverflow question [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The answers on the link you sent me seem a bit too complicated for me, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: @JakeChristensen yeah, what u r trying to do is a bit complicated, but it's not as bad as it seems though ;)

Comment: Alright, I ignored all the complex stuff and just used the location.search. I'll write my own function in order to get the values out of the string. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The function is written incorrectly. Check your javascript console for errors. Here is am example of ways to write functions in javascript:

```
    var navigate = function() { window.location = "myPage.html?myVar=1"; }
```

OR

```
    function navigate() { window.location = "myPage.html?myVar=1"; }
```

I word of caution, the name `navigate` is too general. I would name it something like `navigateToMyPage`.

I reread the question and realized that you are looking for a way to get a parameter from the url.

You will want to do something like this:

```
    var navigateToMyPage = function() { window.location = "myPage.html?" + location.search; }
```

Here is a related question and solution: 
[How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)

OR

If you want to pass a javascript variable value you could do this:

```
    var myVar = 1 + 1;
    var navigateToMyPage = function() { window.location = "myPage.html?myVar=" + myVar; }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**The query string - on the client-side and on the server-side**

The [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is not processed automatically into variables by Javascript,  which is a client-side scripting language. This is usually done by server-side scripting languages, like PHP.

For example, on the server-side in PHP, you will usually have the query string values automatically assigned to the `$_GET` array, or `$_GET['myVar']` in this case. But in Javascript this is not the case, and you will need to process the query string yourself.

**The fragment identifier - passing URL values to Javascript**

In Javascript, the most common way to pass values through the URL is actually through the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and *not* through the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

For example, you can pass two variables like so:

```
myPage.html#myVar=1&myOtherVar=2
```

In JavaScript the `location.hash` variable will be automatically assigned the value `#myVar=1&myOtherVar=2` which you can further process like this:

```
var location_vars = [];
var location_vars_temp = location.hash.replace('#',''); // Remove the hash sign
location_vars_temp     = location_vars_temp.split('&'); // Break down to key-value pairs
for (i=0; i < location_vars_temp.length; i++) {
    location_var_key_val = location_vars_temp[i].split('='); // Break down each pair
    location_vars[location_var_key_val[0]] = location_var_key_val[1];
}
```

At this point `location_vars` will be an array populated with the values passed, and you will be able to reference them with `location_vars['myVar']` and `location_vars['myOtherVar']`